# Publish a file fails - cannot access web link (a file is no longer published)

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've used Ubuntu One in the past to publish files and share the file's web link with colleagues.  But no more.

Running ubuntu 12.04

I right click on a file (a synchronized file with green check) and go to the ubuntu menu.  The only available selection is Publish.  I click publish and I receive a message on the screen "a file is no longer published".  If I right click on the file name now all the Ubuntu menu selections are grayed out.  When I go to one.ubuntu.com all the files are there... I just cannot publish and get the link.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/1193274

It has been critical for weeks, yet still no fix.

One should be iminent in the next major update.

Very frustrating bug indeed!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your account is not verified. You can check that at https://login.ubuntu.com/+emails